# Optional parameter with setParameterList in HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have a query with optional parameter

```
"SELECT ClinicId,Name from Clinic where :ClinicIds is NULL OR ClinicId IN :ClinicIds"

List<int> ClinicIds = null;
```

I'm passing the parameter as following

```
q.SetParameterList("ClinicIds", ClinicIds);
```

Because ClinicId is an optional parameter. If I pass null to SetParameterList I'm getting exception. Any idea how I can pass an optional parameter(null value) to SetParameterList.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using HQL, use a `Criteria` query.  Its designed to be more programmatic than HQL, in that you use straight Java code to assemble your query, which enables you to use if-then logic.  So, instead of either concatenating HQL, or having two different HQL queries which you need to independently maintain, you have one `Criteria` query which accounts for both situations.  Example:

```
//SELECT ClinicId,Name from Clinic where :ClinicIds is NULL OR ClinicId IN :ClinicIds
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Clinic.class);
if(ClinicIds == null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ClinicId", null));
} else {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.eq("ClinicId", null), 
            criteria.add(Restrictions.in("ClinicId", ClinicIds));
        )
    );
}
return criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That would generate invalid SQL.

You need to change the HQL depending on whether there are `ClinicIds`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like:

```
"SELECT ClinicId,Name from Clinic where -1 in (:ClinicIds)  OR ClinicId IN :ClinicIds"
```

and

```
if(ClinicIds == null or ClinicIds.isEmpty()){
    ClinicIds = new List<int>();
    ClinicIds.add(-1);
}

q.SetParameterList("ClinicIds", ClinicIds);
```

just a trick